# Only two workspaces in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04. I used to have 9 workspaces. In 19.04, on first boot, I only had two workspaces, but once I dragged a window from the first to the second workspace (initially empty) in *Activities*, a third workspace appeared, and once I dragged a window into the new third workspace a fourth workspace appeared, etc. So in this manner I was able to recover 9 workspaces.

However, after rebooting, now there are only two workspaces, and even if I place a window onto the second workspace, no third workspace appears.

How do I get more than two workspaces in 19.04?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Ubuntu 19 has dynamic workspaces, meaning it will create more as you need them, however if you want them to be static, you can install the Gnome Tweaks from Ubuntu Software or by:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
```

Then just head to workspaces and set them to the number of static desktops you want.
[image: Gnome Tweaks - Workspaces]

Hope it did help.